# Retrieve current user name and password from OAuth

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, oauth

In a C# MVC app that is using the OAuth login method, how do you retrieve the decrypted password for the current logged in user?

I know

> User.Identity.GetUserName()

Gets the user name but, in the table AspNetUseres is a PasswordHash column with the hashed password and I want to be able to retrieve that and decrypt it if needed in the app.  I can retrieve the hashed string fine but unsure how to convert it into text...

Comment: Read this: http://plaintextoffenders.com/faq/devs

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The whole point of hashing is to obscure data in such a way so you can verify it, but can't see the actual value.

To be able to encrypt / decrypt values, you would need to set up password encryption, not hashing.

But you shouldn't be decrypting user passwords anyway. If you want to mention *why* you need the password, perhaps someone here could suggest an alternative way of getting what you want.

Comment: Hi Jay,  I wanted to use the username and password of the user to create a T-SQL login for their database, and also use it as a login in a connection string.

Comment: @RobboLew: you really don't want that, reconsider your approach to not to require an extra SQL login for each user logging into your app. I barely think of any real-life scenario where this could not be avoided.